# Looking for example of complex series that converges for a given value and diverges at another

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I am  looking for an example of a complex series such that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_nz^n$ converges for $z=4-i$ but diverges for $z=2+3i$ , where $c_n$'s are all real numbers . Please help , thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such series.
$$|4-i|=\sqrt{17}>|2+3\,i|=\sqrt{13}.$$
If $\sum c_nz^n$ converges for $z=4-i$, it converges for all $z$ with $|z|<\sqrt{17}$.

Comment: Aguirre : Can you please mention the theorems(properties) you are using and does the argument still holds if we do not necessarily require the $c_n$'s to be reals , just complex numbers ?

Comment: Aren't you assuming absolute convergence ... ?

Comment: @user123733: No, he isn't. And it doesn't matter whether the $c_n$ are real or complex. For _every_ sequence $(c_n)$ of (real or complex) numbers, the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nz^n$ has a well-defined radius of convergence $r \in \mathbb  R_{\ge0} \cup \{\infty\}$ such that the series converges if $|z| < r$ and diverges if $|z| > r$. Note that if $|z|=r$, the series may converge or diverge; this is where absolute convergence may be important. But in your case, it is not relevant.

Comment: @TonyK : So here , the radius of convergence is $<\sqrt{17}$ ?

Comment: @user123733: No, you have it backwards. From the fact that your series converges for $z=4-i$, we know that the radius of convergence is $\ge \sqrt{17}$.

Comment: @user123733 I was in class and have not read your comments until now. TonyK has given you precise answers to your questions.